# How to connect SQLite to php ERROR

Tags: php

> this is my code. I am using xampp version 7.when i run this code output for like this (Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlite\index.php) .Default included sqlite3 dll file in /php/ directory and php.ini file included extension=php_sqlite3.dll

```
<?php
  class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
     function __construct()
     {
       $this->open('company.db');
     }
    }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
     echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

> how run sqlite in xampp version 7

Comment: Did you uncomment/ activate extension=php_sqlite3.dll in your php.ini?

Comment: check phpinfo() and see if the drivers for sqlite are installed properly ?

Comment: yeah  JYoThI it's installed SQLite Library 3.8.10.2

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and it worked for me

```
<?php
  class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
     function __construct()
     {
       $this->open('mydb.sq3');
     }
    }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
     echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

The extension of the sqlite3 database should be .sq3 and not .db